# Creating a Batch file that pings google constantly and testing the response time

Tags: batch-file, testing, cmd, ping

I'm trying to create a batch file that will constantly ping google.com and check the response time - "time=Xms".

- If the time <= 39ms the text of that ping(or the background) should
  be green.
- If the time > 40ms and < 80ms the text of that ping(or the
  background) should turn orange.
- If the time >= 80ms the text of that ping(or the background) should
  turn red.

I have this batch at the moment which pings google every 3 seconds changes the background from green to red if the response fails:

```
    @echo off
:color 97

:start
PING -n 1 www.google.com 
call :color
goto :start

:color
    IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
        COLOR 27
    ) else (
        COLOR 47
    ping -n 1 127.0.0.1 >nul
    COLOR 74
    ping -n 1 127.0.0.1 >nul
    COLOR 47
    )
    ping -n 3 127.0.0.1 >nul
    GOTO:EOF
```

This works fine but I don't know how to test response times.

Comment: Take a look at this.  It doesn't do the color changing bit, but it has the code to evaluate ping response times.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35591855/writing-a-batch-file-to-detect-ping-anomalies/35633613#35633613

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some quirks.

a) you have to get the desired value of `ping` to a variable. Use a `for` to get it.

b) you can't compare it directly, because `if` compares strings, not numbers (`2` is bigger than `10`). Add leading zeros to the string (and afterwards cut it to a fixed length)

c) `cmd` has no native way of coloring single lines (or characters). It can be done with pure `cmd`, but I think, `powershell` is a much better way to do it.

```
@echo off
:loop
set "tim=unreachable"
for /f "tokens=7 delims== " %%i in ('PING -n 1 www.google.com ^|find "TTL"') do set "tim=%%i"
set "ti=0000%tim%"
set "ti=%ti:~-6,-2%"
if %ti% leq 0040 powershell write-host -foreground green %tim% & goto :loop
if %ti% leq 0080 powershell write-host -foreground yellow %tim% & goto :loop
powershell write-host -foreground red %tim% & goto :loop
```

Comment: Awesome! this is what I was trying to achieve. Cheers

Comment: if you use `set /a` to declare variables, it will treat them like numbers.

Comment: @Wes: there are no numbers in batch. The only variable type is STRING (`set /a` is able to interpret them as numbers but also always returns a STRING)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
@echo off
Title Echo Ping Reply
mode con cols=57 lines=6
::Choose how many seconds you must wait for the refresh
Set MyPause=3
:color 97

:start
CLS
echo.
ping www.google.com | findstr /i "TTL"
Timeout /Nobreak /t %MyPause% > Nul
call :color
goto :start

:color
    IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
        COLOR 27
    ) else (
        COLOR 47
    ping -n 1 127.0.0.1 >nul
    COLOR 74
    ping -n 1 127.0.0.1 >nul
    COLOR 47
    )
    ping -n 3 127.0.0.1 >nul
    GOTO:EOF
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but from what I can understand this doesnt check the amount of time taken for pings response. I'm pretty dependant on my ping (time=Xms) being low and need a way to check it. At the moment it looks like this is just checking that the ping happens, not how fast/slow it happens (the amount of time taken). I just dont know how to place the "time=X ms" into a variable so that it can be used in a if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Because sometimes PowerShell isn't an option, I figured I'd piece some things together and do this all as a batch script.
[Writing a batch file to detect ping anomalies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35591855/writing-a-batch-file-to-detect-ping-anomalies/35633613#35633613)
[How to have multiple colors in a Windows batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339649/how-to-have-multiple-colors-in-a-windows-batch-file/10407642#10407642)

```
:: usage: badpings-color.bat [ip adress | hostname] 

@echo off
set /a warnlimit=79 :: greater than this value is red
                    :: between the two values is yellow
set /a goodlimit=39 :: less than or equal to this value is green

if "%1"=="" (
    set pingdest=google.com
    ) else (
    set pingdest=%1
    )

echo Pinging %pingdest%.
::echo Logging replies over %limit%ms.
echo Press Ctrl+C to end.

:Loop
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-6" %%a in (`ping -n 1 %pingdest% ^| findstr "Request Reply request"`) do (
    set var=%%a %%b %%c %%d %%e %%f
    set pingtimestr=%%e
    )

if "%pingtimestr%"=="find" (
    echo Ping request could not find host %pingdest%. Please check the name and try again.
    goto End
    ) 
if "%pingtimestr%"=="host" (
    set /a pingtime=%warnlimit%+1   
    ) 
if not defined pingtimestr (
    set /a pingtime=%warnlimit%+1
    )
if "%pingtimestr:~0,4%"=="time" (
    set /a pingtime=%pingtimestr:~5,-2% 
    )

if %pingtime% LEQ %goodlimit% (
    call :c 02 "[%time%] %var%" /n
    goto EndOfLoop
    )
if %pingtime% LEQ %warnlimit% (
    call :c 0E "[%time%] %var%" /n
    goto EndOfLoop
    )
if %pingtime% GTR %warnlimit% (
    call :c 0C "[%time%] %var%" /n
    goto EndOfLoop
    )

:EndOfLoop
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
Goto Loop

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: this section is from 
:: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339649/how-to-have-multiple-colors-in-a-windows-batch-file/10407642#10407642

:c
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:colorPrint Color  Str  [/n]
setlocal
set "s=%~2"
call :colorPrintVar %1 s %3
exit /b

:colorPrintVar  Color  StrVar  [/n]
if not defined DEL call :initColorPrint
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
pushd .
':
cd \
set "s=!%~2!"
:: The single blank line within the following IN() clause is critical - DO NOT REMOVE
for %%n in (^"^

^") do (
  set "s=!s:\=%%~n\%%~n!"
  set "s=!s:/=%%~n/%%~n!"
  set "s=!s::=%%~n:%%~n!"
)
for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%s in ("!s!") do (
  if "!" equ "" setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
  if %%s==\ (
    findstr /a:%~1 "." "\'" nul
    <nul set /p "=%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%"
  ) else if %%s==/ (
    findstr /a:%~1 "." "/.\'" nul
    <nul set /p "=%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%"
  ) else (
    >colorPrint.txt (echo %%s\..\')
    findstr /a:%~1 /f:colorPrint.txt "."
    <nul set /p "=%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%"
  )
)
if /i "%~3"=="/n" echo(
popd
exit /b

:initColorPrint
for /f %%A in ('"prompt $H&for %%B in (1) do rem"') do set "DEL=%%A %%A"
<nul >"%temp%\'" set /p "=."
subst ': "%temp%" >nul
exit /b

:cleanupColorPrint
2>nul del "%temp%\'"
2>nul del "%temp%\colorPrint.txt"
>nul subst ': /d
exit /b

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:End
```