# Change Color in Command Prompt Based on Result?

Tags: command-line, cmd, ping

Bit of a long stretch here.

If I want to run a continuous ping command, is it possible to have the output listed in a different color if lets say the result is beyond a certain point?

Example:

Ping result comes back with 22ms, white
Ping result comes back with 300+, red

Is that at all possible? Will I need to make a batch file instead?

The script listed below works REALLY well. However, I need some additional action with it. When an IP address times out, this script does nothing. It just sits waiting for the next ping. Is there anyway to incorporate that?

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35654701/2152082)

Comment: Script updated to handle timeout

Answer (score 2):

A rudimentary solution would be something along the lines of.

```
  @setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
set /p ipaddr="Enter ip or url: eg localhost or google.co.za or 192.168.0.1 "
set /p cutoff="enter minimum good reply ms: eg 300 "
set /a res = 0 - 1 
:loop
for /f "tokens=7,9" %%a in ('ping -n 1 !ipaddr!') do (
set /a res = 0 - 1 
  if "%%a"=="Average" (
  set a=%%b
  set /a res=!a:~0,-2!
  )
)

IF %res% == -1 (
  COLOR 2
  echo %ipaddr% failed to respond in time
)
IF %res% LEQ %cutoff% (
    IF %res% NEQ -1 (
        COLOR 2
        echo %ipaddr% responded in %res%ms
    )
)else (
    COLOR 4
    echo %ipaddr% responded in %res%ms
)
ping -n 3 127.0.0.1 >nul: 2>nul:
goto :loop

endlocal
```

Save it to a .cmd file and then just double click it

Comment: You sir, are amazing. I modified it very slightly but that is PERFECT.

Comment: I actually have another request. If the ping request times out, will that script still change the color or will it just end the script?

Comment: Updated script to handle case of when the site times out